# ATTiny85 Interrupt id vs pin when programming with Arduino

Tags: attiny

I am using an Arduino Uno with the Arduino as ISP sketch to program an ATtiny85.

I followed this [tutorial](http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695) to set up to program the ATtiny, and successfully got it to run Blink and an interrupt-free version of my program.

I then added an interrupt triggered by a button and got it working on the Arduino Uno (with a software debounce in the ISR). Now I want to run that sketch, with appropriate pin changes, on the ATtiny. Which pins correspond to which interrupt IDs for `attachInterrupt()`?

Or can I not use `attachInterrupt()`? If I can't, how do I do set up an interrupt on an ATtiny85?

Comment: attiny is kind of a piece of crap. Get [arduino-tiny](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/) instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `attiny is kind of a piece of crap`. I assume you refer to the device? If that is the case then how does an Arduino core change anything? The "instead" statement is what confuses me.

Comment: No I think Ignacio refers to the attiny library that is referenced by the tutorial.

Comment: I am indeed talking about the extension module for the IDE.

Comment: In arduino-tiny you can use the constant `EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT_0` for `INT0` at physical pin 7

Comment: @Gerben - Got an implementation example?

Comment: `attachInterrupt(EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT_0, blink, CHANGE);`

Answer (score 5):

You can setup interrupts on the Attiny with some different code, but it works the same way. It's important to note that PIN Change Interrupts are triggered at BOTH Rising and Falling Edge

Pins:
[image]

Using the [Arduino-Tiny Cores](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/)

Below is a sample code which used a Pin Change Interrupt on PB1 which switches an LED on and off on PB4.

```
//Includes
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define INTERRUPTPIN PCINT1 //this is PB1 per the schematic
#define PCINT_VECTOR PCINT0_vect  //this step is not necessary
#define DATADIRECTIONPIN DDB1 //Page 64 of data sheet
#define PORTPIN PB1 //Page 64
#define READPIN PINB1 //page 64
#define LEDPIN 4 //PB4

#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit)) //OR
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit)) //AND

/*
 * Alias for the ISR: "PCINT_VECTOR" (Note: There is only one PCINT ISR. 
 * PCINT0 in the name for the ISR was confusing to me at first, 
 * hence the Alias, but it's how the datasheet refers to it)
 */

static volatile byte LEDState; //variable used within ISR must be declared Volatile.

void setup() {
    cli();//disable interrupts during setup
    pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT); //we can use standard arduino style for this as an example
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW); //set the LED to LOW
    LEDState = 0; //we use 0 for Low state and 1 for High
    PCMSK |= (1 << INTERRUPTPIN); //sbi(PCMSK,INTERRUPTPIN) also works but I think this is more clear // tell pin change mask to listen to pin2 /pb3 //SBI
    GIMSK |= (1 << PCIE);   // enable PCINT interrupt in the general interrupt mask //SBI

    DDRB &= ~(1 << DATADIRECTIONPIN); //cbi(DDRB, DATADIRECTIONPIN);//  set up as input  - pin2 clear bit  - set to zero
    PORTB |= (1<< PORTPIN); //cbi(PORTB, PORTPIN);// disable pull-up. hook up pulldown resistor. - set to zero
    sei(); //last line of setup - enable interrupts after setup

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //If you connect a debounced pushbutton to PB2 and to VCC you can tap the button and the LED will come on
  //tap the button again and the LED will turn off.

}


//this is the interrupt handler
ISR(PCINT_VECTOR)
{
  //Since the PCINTn triggers on both rising and falling edge let's just looks for rising edge
  //i.e. pin goes to 5v
  byte pinState;
  pinState = (PINB >> READPIN)& 1; //PINB is the register to read the state of the pins
  if (pinState >0) //look at the pin state on the pin PINB register- returns 1 if high
  {
   if (LEDState == 0)
   {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN,HIGH); //you can use Arduino Code or LowerLevel Code to write to the register
    LEDState = 1; 
    }
   else
   {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN,LOW);
    LEDState = 0;
    }
  }


}
```

If you're going to be using the ATTiny85, I highly suggest you read through the data sheet to understand better how to program these chips at a lower level of code....It took me a while for it to start to make sense.

Comment: The ISR should be `PCINT0_vect`, see the include file iotnx5.h. `#define PCINT0_vect _VECTOR(2)`.  Or at least, that is how it is in my distribution.

Comment: Why use `PCINTn`, when there is `INT0` on `PB2`?

Comment: @NickGammon you're correct. I had some Alias defined in the code that I forgot to include. (Pun intended).I updated my answer.

Comment: @RSM INT0 is the timer 0 interrupt..not the pin change interrupt(PCINTn). AttachInterrupt in Arduino is a Pin Change Interrupt.

Comment: Interrupts which occur because of a timer that affect a pin happen on `OCnx` pins. `INT0` is a hardware input interrupt, specific to that pin, read through the interrupt.h file in avr-gcc. also you should look at [this](http://marcusjenkins.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ARDUINO_V2.png) look closely at pins 2 and 3, which arduino uses as interrupts and see that it is `INT0` & `INT1` respectively. Also you should take a look at the arduino core files, like `WInterrupts.h` and see it uses `INT0`, `PCINTx` [is a group of pins](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/515617#comment-515617)

Comment: @RSM we're talking about Attiny85 Chip. _INT0_ is a level change interrupt which can be hardware programmed to trigger on Rising Edge OR Falling Edge and _PCINTn_ is a Pin Change interrupt which triggers the ISR on BOTH Rising and Falling edges. _INT0_ also has it's own ISR.

Comment: `PCINTn` is a ***WHOLE REGISTER*** PB0 - PB5, i.e. you would have to pick out which pin had a trigger in the ISR, more time wasted in the routine, also **all interrupts are level change or edge triggered**, don't see your point??? I also know its the t85, the WInterrupts.h for tiny libraries also uses `INT0`. Hardware interrupts can be triggered on change too. To reiterate [this AVRfreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/515617#comment-515617) post by clawson #2, the interrupt occurs at a change, or on the edges. `INT0` is a dedicated interrupt? where is the confusion

Comment: @RSM  no confusion. You're totally wrong about the register. Setting the PCMSK register enables only the pin(s) you want to allow to call the interrupt. Not ALL pins. Yes, all of those interrupts call the SAME ISR. So, if you have PB0 - PB5 all as interrupts enabled, then I think you're using the wrong chip for your application. In my example only PCINT1 causes the ISR to be called. It is called at BOTH rising edge and falling edge, so you may need to check if the Pin is High Or Low within the ISR. Checkout the data sheet chapter 9 on interrupts.

Comment: @GisMofx - I can see this is going to go in circles, I'm right, you're right... Lets leave it at that. For simplicity I would use `INTn` first. Your answer is good for pointing out another way  though. also add `#include <avr/interrupt.h>` if in the arduino ide.

Comment: @RSM Thanks. Ok. But I personally don't use INT0 on the Attiny because that pin is used for I2C/USI/SPI. Yes you're also correct you need the #include for interrupt

Comment: @GisMofx:  May I suggest you rework your answer to provide a complete, compilable example? Also move your comments about the mask into it to clarify. You use `(1 << INTERRUPTPIN)` in some places, but `cbi(DDRB, DATADIRECTIONPIN)` in others, which is a bit inconsistent. How about `DDRB &= ~(1 << DATADIRECTIONPIN)` ? You might also want to mention the difference between pin-change interrupts and external interrupts.

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks for the Tip. I've added a full sample code that compiles which uses an interrupt to turn an LED on and off.